# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No line matching interface Clip is supported

Tags: java, swing, clip, wave

Nearly 1 month my program worked fine, but today im getting the error above when starting it. 
The error comes up in this line:

```
sounds.put(key, (Clip)AudioSystem.getLine(new Line.Info(Clip.class)));
```

I have no idea why. 
After i read the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808560/error-playing-sound-java-no-line-matching-interface-clip-supporting-format), i reinstalled eclipse, deleted metadata and so on, but the error still comes up. 
The code is to 100% right, but any way ill post the code near the error:

```
protected SoundArchive(String soundArchive, boolean debugFrame){
    f = new File(this.getClass().getResource("../" + soundArchive).toString().substring(5)).listFiles();
    sounds = new HashMap<String, Clip>();
    try{
        for(int i = 0; i < f.length; i++){
            String key = f[i].toString().split("\\\\")[f[i].toString().split("\\\\").length - 1].split("\\.")[0];
            sounds.put(key, (Clip)AudioSystem.getLine(new Line.Info(Clip.class)));
            sounds.get(key).open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(f[i]));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
    if(debugFrame) debugFrame();
}
```

So, does anyone know what i have to do now? I've my back to the wall....

Comment: Looks like you changed something on the executing system - maybe deactivated/disconnected some audio devices?

Comment: Also have a look at the java doc for AudioSystem: "IllegalArgumentException - if the system does not support at least one line matching the specified Line.Info object through any installed mixer"

Comment: first comment: hmmm ill look at this.  2 comment: but i worked all the time... 3 comment: the link is in my question...