# IllegalArgumentException with opening .wav files in Java

Tags: java, audio, wav

I got a bunch of audio files from a client which at some point in the program need to play. Only a few of these .wav files play when I call them, but most don't and give me an IllegalArgumentException. I tried many different code examples of how to play .wav files in Java but none worked for me and I don't know why. Currently I'm using this, which came from another stackOverflow question/answer:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
    import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
    import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
    import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
    import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;

    /**
     * Handles playing, stoping, and looping of sounds for the game.
     * @author Tyler Thomas
     *
     */
    public class Sound {
        private final int BUFFER_SIZE = 128000;
        private AudioInputStream audioStream;
        private SourceDataLine sourceLine;
        /**
         * @param filename the name of the file that is going to be played
         */
 public void playSound(String filename){
try {
    audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(filename));
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    sourceLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioStream.getFormat()));
    sourceLine.open(audioStream.getFormat());
} catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
sourceLine.start();
int nBytesRead = 0;
byte[] abData = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
while (nBytesRead != -1) {
    try {
        nBytesRead = audioStream.read(abData, 0, abData.length);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (nBytesRead >= 0) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        int nBytesWritten = sourceLine.write(abData, 0, nBytesRead);
    }
}
sourceLine.drain();
sourceLine.close();
}
}
```

If I use this to play my file I get the following Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No line matching interface SourceDataLine supporting format PCM_FLOAT 44100.0 Hz, 32 bit, stereo, 8 bytes/frame,  is supported.
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getLine(Unknown Source)
at Sound.playSound(Sound.java:29)
```

Extra, when I open the file with a regular media player it has no problems. So the files are not corrupted or anything.

Comment: You'll need wav files in a correct format.

Comment: I tried changing the format before opening, but it gave me the same error.

Comment: Have you seen this? (possible duplicate)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808560/error-playing-sound-java-no-line-matching-interface-clip-supporting-format

Comment: and how did you try changing it?

Comment: This is saying that nothing can output audio in that format. This is probably the PCM_FLOAT since most output uses PCM_SIGNED or PCM_UNSIGNED. You need to convert to audio format.

Comment: I see that there is something wrong with the format. I don't know how to fix this. How do I change the format of the file before playing it? The changes I tried were probably not very  good, I've never worked with audio files before and don't see how I can fix this problem and change the format.